# Cannot add collection view to two view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am have added collection view to two of my view controllers and when I click on the cell in the first view controller (TabBar.swift) it should go to the second view controller and vice Versa, but for some reason, the app crashes when I launch.

Here is the code for the first view controller: **TabBar.swift**

```
struct OpenViewController {
var viewController: UIViewController

}
class TabBar: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        addCollectionViewConstraints()
    }

    var viewControllerList = [
    OpenViewController(viewController: FirstScreen())
    ]

    // Setup the collection veiw

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cv
    }()

    // Add constraints to the collection view
    func addCollectionViewConstraints() {

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .blue
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the second view controller:
**FirstScreen.swift**

```
struct OpenViewControllerTwo {
    var viewController: UIViewController
}
class FirstScreen: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        addCollectionViewConstraints()

    }

    var viewControllerList = [
        OpenViewControllerTwo(viewController: FirstScreen())
    ]

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cv
    }()

    // Add constraints to the collection view
    func addCollectionViewConstraints() {

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .blue
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension FirstScreen: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    // The number of elements inside the collection view
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Adding the cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)

        // Customize the cells
        cell.backgroundColor = .black
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = collectionView.contentSize.height / 2
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        return cell
    }

    // The witdth and the height of the cell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.height, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }

    // Padding to the cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)
    }

    // Selecting a cell and navigating to another view controller
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let openViewController = self.viewControllerList[indexPath.row]
        self.present(openViewController.viewController, animated: false)

    }

}
```

Crash log:

[image: Crash log]

Comment: Could you put your crash log?

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: I don't see any problem, Could you push your demo project to github?

Comment: Hey I'm not very familiar with github, should I create a repository?

Comment: Yep, You can create free repository. Very easy

Comment: Oh ok I will do that

Comment: I created a repository, I'm not sure if I've created it the right way. here is the link: https://github.com/killmontag/CollectionViewNavBar.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting memory issue because of viewControllerList is initialised in loops.
Just declare variable like this

```
var viewControllerList = [OpenViewController]()
```

then assign value like this in viewDidLoad.

```
viewControllerList = [
            OpenViewController(viewController: FirstScreen())
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that code in FirstScreen

```
var viewControllerList = [
    OpenViewControllerTwo(viewController: FirstScreen())
]
```

When FirstScreen init, viewControllerList will init all call FirstScreen. 
It created recursive recursive. Please change above code, put another class, ex: In FirstClass

```
var viewControllerList = [
    OpenViewControllerTwo(viewController: SecondClass())
]
```